# how to shorten linux command to one line

Tags: linux, command

I am sorry that I didn't write a related title, but I couldn't think of one.
So my question is:
do you know, in linux. When, for example you type
telnet then press enter
then o ip.add.re.sss
how can u do this in one line? yeah I know for telnet I can just type telnet ip.add.re.sss and press enter and it will connect, I couldn't think of a better example, but some commands dont work this way, I have to press enter and enter the "command" then put my other commands
is there a way to simulate the pressing of the "enter" button ?
to be something like : telnet (magic character or something) o ip.add.re.sss

Answer (score 2):

Look at the concept of pipelines - the use the output of one command as the input to the next, so

```
echo "o ip.add.re.sss" | telnet
```

will do the trick. Mind though, that pipelining is permanent, you need to input all or nothing  via it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply :)
but actually I have tried that but it doesn't work.
ok, to be more specific this is what I am trying to use:
https://github.com/vysheng/tg
It's an IM
so when I compile the code I have to type
./telegram
then enter 
then: send_message friendname message
I tried to pipe but it didn't work

Comment: This one uses readline input, so piping should work. If you use `echo` as an inputter, make sure you have the `-e` option!

Comment: I'm sorry for being a noob :D
this is what I've tried 
echo -e "msg Rana test2" | ./telegram
it doesn't work I don't know why

Comment: oh ok, so it is working fine, but there is a bug in the program, so it has to load the list of my friends first before I can send a friend a msg, so when I use the piping it does the command "msg Rana test2" before it loads the list
Is there anyway around that?

Comment: Use `sleep` to wait before starting input, if loading the list does not need any command: `(sleep 5 ; echo -e "msg Rana test2") | ./telegram`

Comment: awesome man :D
it worked, thank you so much
I've always wondered how to do that.